# Android - full screen transparent button

Tags: java, android, button, android-layout

Is it possible to make a full screen button that is transparent so no matter where the user clicks the button is activated?

Below is some basic java that shows a button and when pressed starts a new intent. I also added the main.xml layout but I am not sure how to update it so the buttons fills the screen but is transparent.

```
package com.MeetingManager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MeetingManager extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MeetingManager.this,CreateMeeting.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });

}



}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/meetingbg"
    >
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow5">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If listening for user interaction via tapping on screen is your aim, I would recommend added a touch listener to your LinearLayout. This removes the need for a Button.

E.g.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_layout);

layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/your_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/meetingbg"
    >
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow5">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

You may have to include the following imports:

```
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
```

---

Comment: Thanks! +1 I am implement now.

Comment: When I try adding the code above it is trying to rewrite my R.java file (which isn't possible) Am I missing something? I updated my code above.

Comment: I've edited my source to show how to add an ID to your layout in the XML and how to grab this programatically before you add the onTouchListener. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for all your help: your assitance made it so my "layout" resolves but now my View.OnTouchListener is showing the error: The type new View.OnTouchListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnTouchListener.onTouch(View, MotionEvent)   and my MotionEvent is showing the error: The type new View.OnTouchListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnTouchListener.onTouch(View, MotionEvent)

Comment: I've edited the source again to include the return type and also imports you may need.

Answer (score 1):

try to use null in the background `android:background="@null"`

Comment: So to remove the background of the button?  How would I get the button to overlay all of the other elements on the page?

Comment: you can use RelativeLayout if you have only one button
also check the method [bringChildToFront()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#bringChildToFront%28android.view.View%29)